# IKJEFT01 PARM文の使用可否について

Tags: jcl

IKJEFT01にてプログラムを実行する際、PARM文の指定は可能ですか。
PARMより処理判断の情報を得るためです。

```
//SYSTSIN  DD   *
DSN SYSTEM(DB2B)
RUN PROGRAM(PGM00001) PLAN(PGM00001)
PARMS('PGM,1,2,X')       -
LIB('PGM.BTCH.LOAD')
END
```